# Linear discriminant analysis from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm having an issue with sklearn.discriminant_analysis not recognizing the inputs.

I've already changed all of my labels from str to numerical values.

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
print(labels)
print(type(labels))
Fit_Features_2 = LDA(n_components = 1)
Fit_Features_2 = LDA.fit(features_NiFe, labels)

#The type for labels
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the instance of LDA.

change

```
Fit_Features_2 = LDA.fit(features_NiFe, labels)
```

to

```
Fit_Features_2 .fit(features_NiFe, labels)
```

Make sure that the labels is of type array. 
So convert the dataframe to numpy array using `df.to_numpy()`

Also check the dimensions of X and y parameters of fit function

```
        X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training data.
        y : array, shape (n_samples,)
            Target values.
```

Comment: I did that and I got this error- so I need to change labels into an array? Even though features is also a pd dataframe? C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:578: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

Comment: So I changed y into a 1d array,labels = np.array(labels)
print(labels)
labels = labels.reshape(1,24)

Fit_Features_2 = LDA(n_components = 2)
Fit_Features_2 = Fit_Features_2.fit(features_NiFe, labels) and now the error is, ValueError: bad input shape (1, 24)

Comment: I think it should be column vector. shape 24, 1

Comment: With that format it still gives the 'please change shape of y' error

Comment: you have to use ```np.squeeze```